# Initialize kotlin ViewModel from Java activity

Tags: java, kotlin, viewmodel

I would like to initialize kotlin ViewModel from java activity class, but I am not able to figure out what to use as paramater for `ViewModelProvider.Factory.from`.

Kotlin ViewModel

```
class QueueViewModel : ViewModel() {   
    companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
                modelClass: Class<T>,
                extras: CreationExtras
            ): T {
                return super.create(modelClass, extras)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java Activity

```
public abstract class BaseQueueActivity extends BaseScreenActivity implements IModule {

    private QueueViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.Factory.from(QueueViewModel.Companion.getFactory())
    ).get(QueueViewModel.class);
 }
```

When I use this, I get `Cannot resolve method 'from(Factory)'` error message. What should I use as the correct input parameter?

Comment: You haven't shown the `from` method. How are we supposed to know?

Comment: `from` is standard method of `ViewModelProvider.Factory` class ([ViewModelProvider.Factory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `from` method requires `ViewModelInitializer` not `ViewModelProvider.Factory` as you can see source code mentioned below

[image]

So you need to change kotlin code as mentioned below

```
class QueueViewModel : ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        var initializer: ViewModelInitializer<QueueViewModel> = ViewModelInitializer(
            QueueViewModel::class.java
        ) {
            QueueViewModel()
        }
    }
}
```

On java side you can do like this

```
private QueueViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.Factory.from(QueueViewModel.Companion.getInitializer())
    ).get(QueueViewModel.class);
```